# Ajax promises with a parent/child function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm using an ajax call with [taggle.js](https://sean.is/poppin/tags) to check typed tag values against a DB. The taggle docs specify to `return false` on the `onBeforeTagAdd` event to prevent a tag from being added, but I know that can't be done with ajax since it's asynchronous. I've seen other SO questions suggesting promises to make functions dependent on the ajax response, but I'm stumped on how I'd use promises when the ajax call is inside the parent function that relies on its response - can anyone give advice? Here's the code with the ajax call:

```
new Taggle('tagexample', {
    onBeforeTagAdd: function(event, tag) {
        // return false here would prevent tag from being added
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"inputcheck.php",
            data:"tag="+tag,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
                if (result == 'no') {
                    // return false here won't work
                }
            }

        });
    },
});
```

Comment: Redesign the application so that you first query all allowed tags from the server into a client array, which you then can use in the `onBeforeTagAdd` event handler without doing any Ajax call there.

Comment: A callback API like you are using either supports asynchronous results  or it doesn't.  If it doesn't, there's nothing you can do from the outside to make it.  You could modify the Taggle source code, you could precheck expected tags so you synchronously have their info or you can change the design to solve your problem another way.

Answer (score -1):

Taggle would need to support promises on the onBeforeTagAdd method, which from looking it does not.

The only thing I can think of that might work is always returning false (after the ajax call is made) and then creating the tag dynamically if yes.

```
new Taggle('tagexample', {
    onBeforeTagAdd: function(event, tag) {
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"inputcheck.php",
            data:"tag="+tag,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
                if (result == 'yes') {
                    // create tag
                }
            }

        });

        return false;
    },
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted.  If the Taggle API does not support asynchronous answers to the validation, there's nothing you can do to make it do that from outside its code.  This answer suggests one possible work-around that isn't perfect, but I'd like to see anyone else come up with a better idea (other than reworking the taggle code itself) before downvoting.